# Facebook unity3d sdk 6.0 does not work in ios simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, unity-game-engine

Facebook requires us to submit the app as a simulator build for them to review.

I did that, but when I run it in simulator, I get the exception:

```
Symbol file /Users/AMI/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/D2633BCE-B3F0-4B4B-910B-34E3F2FFF403/Testing.app/Data/Managed/System.dll.mdb doesn't match image /Users/TESTER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/D2633BCE-B3F0-4B4B-910B-34E3F2FFF403/Testing.app/Data/Managed/System.dll
EntryPointNotFoundException: iosInit

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Facebook.IOSFacebook:iosInit (string,bool,bool,bool,bool,string)

  at Facebook.IOSFacebook.Init (Facebook.InitDelegate onInitComplete, System.String appId, Boolean cookie, Boolean logging, Boolean status, Boolean xfbml, System.String channelUrl, System.String authResponse, Boolean frictionlessRequests, Facebook.HideUnityDelegate hideUnityDelegate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

  at FB.OnDllLoaded () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at FB+CompiledFacebookLoader.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What could be causing this? If I cannot get this to work, I will not be able to submit the app to be approved by Facebook which means we can not make our app work with Facebook.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: It just called the FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity) when app start.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, another plugin have the post build step which modify the same file as facebook does. Disable that and there is no more issue.